# How to upgrade MySQL database schema?

Tags: mysql, database-schema

How to upgrade a production DB schema from a dev DB schema automatically, via command line? The dev version has changes to the schema that need to be made in the production schema, but I cannot lose the data in production.

Comment: What are the changes ..?

Comment: They differ in every upgrade, for example, some column names are different, maybe new tables, maybe something has been altered.

Comment: @AndrewsBAnthony I'm trying to put together a script to automate the move from dev to production.

Comment: Generate sql queries for the changes and keep them in a prop file/xml file and write a script to execute all the queries in the file to execute in all the schemas one by one...

Comment: @AndrewsBAnthony I was hoping there would be an easier, automatic way lol.

Comment: Why don't you write the code and give it away ..? It relatively easy :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## [Schema Migrations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schema_migration)

Most modern projects use a tool to track each individual change to the database, and associate some version number with the change. The database must also have some table to store its current version. That way the tool can query the current version and figure out which (if any) changes to apply.

There are several free tools to do this, like:

- [Liquibase](http://www.liquibase.org)
- [Flyway](https://flywaydb.org)
- [Rails Migrations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2/migrations.html)
- [Doctrine Migrations](http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/migrations.html)
- [SQLAlchemy Migrate](http://sqlalchemy-migrate.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

All of these require that you write meticulous code files for each change as you develop. It would be hard to reverse-engineer a project if you haven't been following the process of creating schema change code all along.

There are tools like [mysqldbcompare](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-utilities/1.6/en/mysqldbcompare.html) that can help you generate the minimal ALTER TABLE statements to upgrade your production database.

There is also a newer free tool called [Shift](https://github.com/square/shift) (I work with the engineer who created it), which helps to automate the process of upgrading your database. It even provides a nice web interface for entering your schema changes, running them as online changes, and monitoring their progress. But it requires quite a lot of experience to use this tool, I wouldn't recommend it for a beginner.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use MySQL WorkBench: https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/
if you want an easy GUI, and cross OS compatible ;)